# Export basemap and vector layers into a single image with OpenLayers 2.11?

Tags: openlayers-2, export

Has anyone been able to export OpenLayers 2.11 map and features as a static image?

This example is exactly what I'd like to do, but it's using OL3 alpha which is not an option for me...

http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html

Thanks!
Vincent

Comment: Check the answers in this thread if the problem is still relevant for you, they might help you to do it programatically (via a script instead of a button):
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130786/programatically-export-openlayers-maps-to-static-image-file